# Run time error in when calling eclipse quick fix programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, runtime-error

I implemented a java plugin capable of fixing comiper errors using Eclipse quick fix. To access the last version of the input program, fist the project open in eclipse is refreshed and then eclipse quick fix is called to fix existing compiler errors. (The input program is changed requarly and I need to first refresh the project and then extract the last version.) The below code (provided as one method) is implemented to do the described work.

```
//Get workspace
IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace(); 
IWorkspaceRoot root = workspace.getRoot();

//Get project
IProject project = root.getProject(projectName);

//Referesh the project
project.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE, null); 
IJobManager jobManager = Job.getJobManager();
jobManager.wakeUp(ResourcesPlugin.FAMILY_AUTO_BUILD);
jobManager.join(ResourcesPlugin.FAMILY_AUTO_BUILD, null);
IJavaProject javaProject = JavaCore.create(project);

//Get ICompilationUnit (classFullName is the full name of class that we need to find its compiler error)
IType iType = javaProject.findType(classFullName);
ICompilationUnit iUnit = iType.getCompilationUnit();

/** Create working copy. It is safer to work with a copy.*/
WorkingCopyOwner owner = iUnit.getOwner();
iUnit = (owner == null ? iUnit.getWorkingCopy(null) : iUnit.getWorkingCopy(owner, null)); 

//Get compilation Unit
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8);
parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
parser.setSource(iCompilationUnit);
parser.setResolveBindings(true); 
CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);

//Get compiler error using eclipse quick fix
for (IProblem iProblem : cu.getProblems()) {

   //If it is an error
   if (iProblem.isError()) {
      int offset = iProblem.getSourceStart();
      int length = iProblem.getSourceEnd() + 1 - offset;
      IInvocationContext context = new AssistContext(iUnit , offset, length);

     ProblemLocation problem = new ProblemLocation(iProblem);

     //Extract Eclipse quick fix proposal.
     ArrayList<IJavaCompletionProposal> proposals = new ArrayList<IJavaCompletionProposal>();
     JavaCorrectionProcessor.collectCorrections(context, new IProblemLocation[] { problem }, proposals);        
 }}
```

At the end we have list of eclipse proposals in **proposals** variable. The program worked fine until today I faced a new compiler error. If I have below example as input program:

```
class Test {
   public void foo(){
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   }
 }
```

I get the below run time error when it wants to consider proposals for line `Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);`

`!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jdt.ui".
!STACK 1
Java Model Exception: Java Model Status [[Working copy] Test.java [in src [in SortExample]]] does not exist] at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.newJavaModelException(JavaElement.java:544)`

I debug the program and find the problem happen in method **collectCorrections** in class **JavaCorrectionProcessor**.

```
public static IStatus collectCorrections(IInvocationContext context, IProblemLocation[] locations, Collection<IJavaCompletionProposal> proposals) {
    ContributedProcessorDescriptor[] processors= getCorrectionProcessors();
    SafeCorrectionCollector collector= new SafeCorrectionCollector(context, proposals);
    for (int i= 0; i < processors.length; i++) {
        ContributedProcessorDescriptor curr= processors[i];
        IProblemLocation[] handled= getHandledProblems(locations, curr);
        if (handled != null) {
            collector.setProblemLocations(handled);
            collector.process(curr);
        }
    }
    return collector.getStatus();
}
```

**IMPORTANT:** I only get this error for specific type of compiler error. For example if the compiler error happens for this line **i = 0** while i is not defined, then i get unresolve variable and the program suggests a solution whitout any problem. Therefore, I think the refresh section should work fine otherwise I should get the error for all types of compiler error in the program.

Comment: My vote goes to you.  I am trying exactly same.  But on line
     "JavaCorrectionProcessor.collectCorrections(context, new IProblemLocation[] { problem }, proposals);"   
I am getting NullPointer error.  I tried various combinations but failed.
Do you have idea? You can mail me on shailendravermag@gmail.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. It happens because of Working Copy as shown in the run time error `Java Model Status [[Working copy] Test.java [in src [in SortExample]]] does not exist]`. After I comment the below lines, every thing works fine.

```
WorkingCopyOwner owner = iUnit.getOwner();
iUnit = (owner == null ? iUnit.getWorkingCopy(null) : iUnit.getWorkingCopy(owner, null));
```

As I said the problem happens for some specific errror. For example it does not happen when I used a integer variable (i = 0) without defining that, but it happens when an entity of a class is used in a second class, but its import statement is not added to the second class.

It happens because the used class is not added to the working copy, and when eclipse wants to find the used class as it is not in the working copy it throw an exception. However, for the first error (i = 0) nothing happen because all information can be obtained from the working copy.